# Using Web Part when adding document to a library

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

When a user uploads a document to a SharePoint library, I need to present them with a few dropdowns and text fields where they can provide some extra info. The dropdowns are going to be populated from a database.

The way I have currently gone about this is create a Web Part which displays a user control. The user control contains the dropdowns. I can add the Web Part to a SharePoint page and it works as expected (pulls data from DB and displays in UC).

However I need this page to display after they have uploaded a document to a library. Would this be achieved using a Workflow?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean that you'd like the extra info to live as a page, and not a web part? Give event receivers a look:

[MSDN Blogs: Event Handlers - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx)
[MSDN Blogs: Event Handlers - Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/18/event-handlers-part-2-building-and-deploying-event-handlers-including-event-handler-starter-solution-kit.aspx)
[MSDN Blogs: Event Handlers - Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/18/event-handlers-part-3-register-event-handlers-plus-free-site-settings-manage-event-handlers-add-on.aspx)
[Event Receivers Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462603%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I mean! I've seen an article explaning how you can include user controls in sp pages without using Web Parts which is useful. I've had a look at event receivers before, so after I hook up an event receiver to the ItemAdded event for the necessary library, I assume I can redirect to my page containing the UC. Next question is, can I add pages to SharePoint?

Comment: There's a wealth of information on the 'net for creating custom pages as well as custom application pages (~/_layouts/yourpage.aspx) in SharePoint. msdn and nothingbutsharepoint are good starting points.